# How to install qmake compiler on Ubuntu

Tags: compiler, qmake

I've been trying to compile VNote but couldn't figure out or find any proper way to install qmake. How can I install it with latest version?

Comment: qmake : "qmake automates the generation of Makefiles". ...... I.e. qmake is a configuration tool for qt, `$ qmake file.pro` will write a Makefile. ..... Install qmake : `sudo apt install qt5-qmake` https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=qmake&searchon=names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile VNote by following their official build documentation at https://vnotex.github.io/vnote/en_us/#!docs/Developers/Build%20VNote.md .

So on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS you have to open terminal and then execute:

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/vnotex/vnote.git vnote.git
cd vnote.git
git submodule update --init --recursive

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev qtbase5-dev-tools libqt5svg5-dev libqt5webenginewidgets5 libqt5webchannel5-dev qtwebengine5-dev

mkdir build
cd build
qmake ../vnote.pro
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install
```

Also please note that VNote is shipped as frequently updated AppImage, so you can [download it](https://github.com/vnotex/vnote/tags) and use.